# Determining the pressure after an adiabatic compression

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, adiabatic

(**Please avoid explaining it with calculus**) 
I need to determine the pressure of air after an adiabatic compression. I have been given a low starting temperature T1 and a high final temperature T2 and then I have also been given a starting pressure p1 and final pressure p2.

How do I then determine the pressure of the air after compression?

I thought in general you should use the adiabatic equations, but you don't know any volumes and you also don't know what the amount of matter for the air in question is, so it's just not possible to calculate the initial volume that way. I've looked all over my books for an answer and can't come up with a meeting to solve it.

It says that in the next task you then calculate the work for 1.00 mol of air supplied during the compression, but in principle you can't use that in an earlier task?

Comment: Isn’t the final pressure P2?

Comment: What is the exact statement of the problem?

Comment: Yeah I wrote it too fast to realize I worded it like that. I don't have P2 as I'm supposed to find P2, since the exact statement is "Determine the pressure of the air after the compression."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you need to combine the equations for a reversible adiabatic compression process in terms of temperature, and the ideal gas equation relating the initial and final equilibrium states, plus the relationship between the specific heats at constant volume and pressure and $R$ for an ideal gas.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean because I don't know what it means to relate things together since English isn't my first language

Comment: By “relate” I mean solving equations simultaneously. I assume you know how to do that

Comment: Yes, I know how to solve equations but I think the case is that I don't have a good enough conceptual understanding to know exactly what equations I should combine. I'm not sure how to relate the initial and final equilibrium states in terms of temperature and the ideal gas equation. In addition to this, I don't understand what the relationship between the specific heats at constant volume and pressure and R for an ideal gas means mathematically.

Comment: You can google each of these equations. This is a homework and exercise question. We can only give guidance, not complete solutions

Comment: That's true. However, I don't think looking them up will help me much in this case because what's bothering me is that I don't have any volumes or any value for the amount of substance. I am trying to substitute the volumes but that doesn't work. Is it possible for you to maybe explain it another way?

Comment: If you are given the type of ideal gas and the initial and final temperatures, then  you will have two equations and two unknowns (P and V)